# Where can I download the source code of SEDarwin project?

Tags: macos, open-source

I am trying to get the source code of SEDarwin project. TrustedBSD page related to Sedarwin(http://www.trustedbsd.org/sedarwin.html) says that that SEDarwin project has been moved to it's own website at www.sedarwin.org.But that website appears to be down.

I am particularly interested in the source code of MAC policy modules and MAC framework.

Any help regarding this is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Ramkumar

Comment: did you try this http://opensource.apple.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending what version of SEDarwin you are looking for [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20111005174320/http://www.sedarwin.org/downloads.html) is a website that might help you.

> SEDarwin Downloads

[image]

If satisfied with the answer to mark it as completed do the above :):

Comment: Thanks a lot.Using the link provided by you, I could download the latest version SEDarwin code.

Comment: You welcome :).

Comment: Do you still have a question on this topic ? or are we done! It still shows it as open question.

Comment: I have no more question on this topic. But, I do not know how to close the question as completed. I have flagged it bringing it to the attention of administrator to close it as completed.

Comment: The mods can not do that for you, see above :)